How can I add multiple themes in my angular app
I want multiple themes for my vendors. I created multiple environments to achieve this.
However, this is the **error **i want to resolve:
enter image description here
package.json:
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "main": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
  "theme1": "ng serve --configuration=theme1 --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
  "theme2": "ng serve --configuration=theme2 --proxy-config proxy.conf.js"
},

angular.json:
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "budgets": [],
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
    "outputHashing": "all"
  },
  "theme1": {
    "budgets": [],
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.theme1.ts"
      }
    ],
    "outputHashing": "all"
  },
  "development": {}
},
"defaultConfiguration": "production"
},
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"configurations": {
  "production": { "browserTarget": "smart-journal:build:production" },
  "theme1": { "browserTarget": "smart-journal:build:theme1" },
  "development": { "browserTarget": "smart-journal:build:development" }
},
"defaultConfiguration": "development"
},

environments/environment.theme1.ts:
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  style: "theme1-styles.css",
  logo: "theme1-logo.png"
};

When i start my app with
"npm run theme1"
or
"npm run theme2"
I want them to run as production and not print the production server error
How can I get my custom configuration environment themes to run as production?
running "npm run main" runs correctly and as production
